# FLUTTER Android Studio BUMBLEBEE: Generating signed bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

When I try to `build > generate signed bundle`
AS complains:

> Generating signed bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle
> plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher

If I click on `Close this dialog and update the plugin`
A further dialog appears (AS Bumblebee) titled `update the Android Gradle plugin` If I hit OK, the dialog vanishes, nothing happens, and I get the same complaint when I try to build a signed app bundle again.

This is really frustrating because I can't upload an app with Googlemaps without signing it. That's my whole app!

OK well similar problems have been answered a few times on StackOverflow, but some of the solutions have become antiquated other solutions don't seem relevant:

1. I can see no way to update Gradle through `File > project structure` in Android Studio Bumblebee.
2. If I try and update Gradle manually in `android/build.gradle`, well it already has gradle 7.03, which is way above 3.2.0. Although Gradle and Android Studio's Gradle plugin may have different version numbers. See the code snippet below.
3. I've tried using Android Studio's search box with 'update Gradle plugin' to no effect.
4. I've hunted around `Preferences > SDK tools`, but no mention of a gradle plugin.
5. Instead of using an app bundle I've tried generating a signed APK, but that has problems too, and the file is larger, so no easy solution.

This is the relevant part of my `android/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
```

FURTHER investigation, `gradle-wrapper.properties` contains this:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip`

Which is a different version number to my `android/build.gradle`:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'`

I'm not sure why they have different numbers.

This is the last hurdle for one app, and a roadblock in another, please help. I'm totally lost, I've begun to think maybe a Kotlin plugin upgrade has caused havoc somehow.

UPDATE
I've reported the issue to Google, via AS's help menu, and in doing so the report said this...

> AS: Bumblebee | 2021.1.1; Kotlin plugin:
> 211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40; Android Gradle Plugin: (plugin
> information not found); Gradle: (gradle version information not
> found); Gradle JDK: version 11.0.11; NDK: from local.properties: (not
> specified), latest from SDK: (not found); LLDB: pinned revision 3.1
> not found, latest from SDK: (package not found); CMake: from
> local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found), from
> PATH: (not found)

That's a lot of things missing! Both gradle and the gradle plugin. I've tried creating a fresh project in AS Bumblebee then asking for a signed bundle but get the same complaint, so it's not because the projects have taken a while.

Any solutions are appreciated. I thought you just downloaded Android Studio and it was all good to go... *sigh*.

UPDATE attempted the solution offered below, but I do not appear to have a Gradle location set, as per picture...

[image: Preferences>Buidl, execution, deployment > build tools > gradle]

Comment: It's for reasons such as this I never upgrade to new versions of Android Studio as soon as they come out.

Comment: Well I upgraded to AS Bumblebee today, it hit stable.

Comment: I have the exact same problem that you have, and did the exact same checks and investigations that you did, with the same result. Mine is also a Flutter app. Any news? I'm stuck without being able to create my bundle either!

Comment: Do you really need to be on the latest gradle version? I'm currently on Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1 with Flutter 2.10.0, Dart 2.16.0 and DevTools 2.9.2. The distributionUrl configured on my gradle-wrapper.properties is `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`, the gradle version on android/build.gradle is `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`. That's what Flutter generates on my machine currently by default at least. Try bumping down the version that you're using by a notch and see if it works for you. Using the most latest gradle plugin doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: In my case, I open android directory instead of root directory, and now I'm able to create Signed Bundle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finaly solve this problem.
I trid all that way mentioned in the question and stell that dump error
[image]
it doesn't look logical. but its work for me.
I closed project in android studio then open `android` folder at my project folder in new a android studio window,

**like this below**
[image]

then it take long time for downloading, analyzing, or... something,

**you can see the layout is not same as main project ....**
[image]

**also build menu has more options...**
[image]

after that tried to build app bundle and everything is good.
I think generating app bundles is not possible in main project file. we need to switch to android folder and generating it.

after all these I searched youtube `generate app bundle android studio flutter`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0GNuoCOtaQ
in this building app bundle in another way that doesn't have these headaches

Answer (score 3):

Well in the end I solved it. In the left hand project files pane I right-clicked on `Android > Open in Android Studio`, Gradle then took a long time reindexing the project and offered to update the project's Gradle version, which this time it did successfully. HALLEYUH!

I seldom push out signed apps, so I'd forgotten the process for doing this, and the fact that the AS Flutter plugin offered me the option of `Tools > build signed app bundle` within the plugin led me away from how I've successfully attained a signed app in the past.

I think really the Flutter team shouldn't offer this option if it's not going to work reliably, but the solution is to do it the old way. Change the IDE back into what I presume is 'Java app' view, and be patient while AS runs around fetching gradle and Android SDK updates, reindexing.  Then seek  `Build > signed app bundle` from there.

Thanks everybody for your attention, and apologies for wasting energies. x Sam

Comment: I was facing same issue, my solution was to build using command line: `flutter build appbundle`.

Answer (score 1):

In Settings, 'Build, Execution, Deployment', 'Build Tools', 'Gradle' I had a 'Use Gradle From' set to a 'Specified Location' and it was breaking the build.  It must have come from some previous version.  I changed it to "'gradle-wrapper.properties' file" and everything went fine.

I also noted a much larger 'aab' file in Bumblebee. I know I added stuff, but not 8 megabytes worth. It was only code, and maybe a thousand lines.

Comment: I did find my increase in size.  It was a library.

Comment: Gradle from? AS Bumblebee gives me ``Gradle user home`` but it's greyed out, not set. Nevertheless thanks for your attention and care.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned the project from `Build>Clean Project` and then a popup menu appeared from bottom which asks me to sync gradle. After clicking `sync` button, gradle was automatically synced and faced no further issues while building app bundle.